# Vue array to table issues

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Having some issues printing array data to a table using Vue. Can someone help me parse the values using vue and put them in a table. See code below image. Without the array of 2 it would work but I'm not sure how to with the response being multiple.

[image]

This is my function in due

//HTML CODE

```
     <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(input, index) in inputs">
          <th>((input.id))</th>
          <th>((input.tracking_number))</th>
          <td>((input.first_name))</td>
          <td>((input.last_name))</td>
          <td>((input.weight))</td>
          <td>((input.description))</td>
          <td>((input.courier))</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

//end HTML

//Vue Code

```
      var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
       data: {
       inputs: [],
       form: {
        scanval: null
       }
       },
       methods: {
        updatetable() {
        this.$http.get('someroute', {params:  {page: this.form}})
        .then(response => {
          if (response.body != "null") {
            console.log(response);
            this.inputs.push({
              id: response.body.id,
              tracking_number: response.body.tracking_number,
              first_name: response.body.first_name,
              last_name: response.body.last_name,
              weight: response.body.weight,
              description: response.body.description,
              courier: response.body.courier
            })
            this.form.scanval = ""
          } else {
            this.form.scanval = "",
            alert("No items found")
          }
        }, response => {
          alert("no item found");
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set `inputs` equal to the response body.

```
this.inputs = response.body
```

This will *replace* the current value of `inputs` with the response. If you would like to *add* the response to `inputs` then you can concatenate the response to `inputs`:

```
this.inputs = this.inputs.concat(response.body)
```

Comment: On the off-chance that `inputs` already has some data (since OP is using `Array.prototype.push` in their code), maybe try `this.inputs = this.inputs.concat(response.body)`

Comment: @Phil Sure :) Added.